# Trying to write the Page Title in VB Script on ASP Pages alt tag

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Hi I'm trying to do something very basic without using Javascript. I would like my page logo's image alt field to contain the title of the page. I would rather use VB Script so that the actual HTML content gets injected in the html markup on the users end.

We currently have the following that does this in Javascript

`<script language=javascript type=text/javascript>
    var writelogo;
    writelogo = "<a href=http://www.mywebsite.com><img SRC=/logo.png alt=\"" + document.title + "\" /></a>";
    document.write(writelogo);
</script>`

I would assumed I could use the VBScript to write the document.title in a simple script and then simply apply it to a variable to look something like this in the static image's alt tag.

Ex `<img src="Logo.jpg" alt="<%=mypageTitle%>">`

Is there an easy way of grabbing the pages title and displaying it in the alt tag with the use of VBScript on a classic asp page? I tried a couple of different things that wasn't working out. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Classic ASP runs on the server side, it can't know the page title which is client side thing. You will have to send XMLHTTP request to the page and parse the raw HTML. Far from basic or simple but that's your only option if you want to avoid client side scripting.

Comment: @ShadowWizard `document.title` reads the text from the `<title>` tag, which is constructed on the *server side*.

Comment: @DavidChilders Do you have a variable `mypageTitle` defined in your ASP code?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers if there was such a variable the code would have worked as-is, thus I doubt that's the case. The OP is interested how to dynamically get the page title from the server side and no, the `<title>` is HTML tag and can be written without any server side code.

Comment: The title tags are static but I do believe that there is a variable for what I'm looking for but it would differ slightly depending on what type of page it is. Some pages would not have any variable to use from the current client side code. What everyone has made perfect sense though and I'll give this another shot by finding my variables. Any further info on pages that use non-dynamic static title tag?

Comment: If you can switch to ASP.NET this becomes trivial by adding `runat="server"` to the `<title>` however such thing doesn't exist in classic ASP.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks to DOM anything in a page can be (re)written on the client side. That doesn't make any particular tag, including `<title>`, a "client side thing".

Comment: @DavidChilders You could define the title as a variable and use that variable for both title and image attributes.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no "easier" way of doing it. The server side doesn't have any special holder for page title. Declaring a holding variable yourself and using it inline when HTML is I think the only way to go. There are alternatives: instead of a variable, you could use a function, or  object's property, if those make more sense in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the Page title is not stored server side, VB will not be able to access the information.

I see your easiest options as one of two...

1. If the pages and titles are already hard-coded, just hard-code in the alt tag too.

Or...

1. Put this in the image alt tag.

   <script>document.write(document.title);</script>

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to use ASP because what you want to do needs to be done before leaving the factory. Yes, ASP can be used to retrieve the content in a title tag and replace a placeholder somewhere on the same page for alt tags, etc.

If you do not have a title tag to play with you can use the page name, or you can retrieve some content from the page to create one. For example you could search the page and trap any wording following the first  tag or first  tag.

If your page is constructed on the fly from database records like a CMS, then it gets a lot easier because you won't need very complex scripting to use the subject line or first few words from the article. This method is most useful for adding title, description, alt tags and keywords to pages created pre-SEO mania.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this page in search of an answer to the same question. Seeing the material shown here inspired me to adjust my thinking cap, and have a go at it. Following is my straightforward solution, taken from a working sandbox page.

```
<head>
    <title>VBScript Date Functions Demonstration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="/css/WebApplication1.CSS">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"href="/css/Widget_Generators.css">
    <script src="/JavaScipt/commonPageHelpers.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="cphSetTitleFromTag()" lang="en-us">
<h1 class="PageTitle" id="spnPageTitle"></h1>
```

Among other things, WebApplication1.css defines a PageTitle class selector as follows.

```
h1.PageTitle
{
    font-family:        Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif ;
    font-size:          14pt ;
    font-weight:        bold ;
    font-style:         normal ;
    color:              purple ;
    text-align:         left ;

    margin-bottom:      1em ;
}
```

The particulars of the definition are immaterial; the point is that such a class exists in the CSS that is either embedded in or linked to your page. Since there are already four pages in this test site, all of which share the same cascading styles, I put them into a separate file, to which all four pages are linked.

Likewise, all four pages link to commonPageHelpers.js, which contains the following code.

```
//  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Define some constants that have broad usage, well beyond their applications
//  herein.
//  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var cLENGTH_OF_EMPTY_STRING = 0;
var cDEFAULT_PAGE_TITLE_SPAN_PLACEHOLDER = "spnPageTitle";
var cTYPEOF_IS_STRING = "string";
var cTYPEOF_IS_UNDEFINED = "undefined";

var cTRUE = 1;
var cFALSE = 0;

var cTHE_EMPTY_STRING = "";

function cphSetTitleFromTag( pstrSpanID )
{
    if ( typeof( pstrSpanID) == cTYPEOF_IS_UNDEFINED )
    {   // Degenerate case 1 of 3: Use the default placeholder span ID.
        document.getElementById( cDEFAULT_PAGE_TITLE_SPAN_PLACEHOLDER ).innerHTML = document.title;
    }   // TRUE block, if ( typeof (pstrSpanID) == cTYPEOF_IS_UNDEFINED )
    else if (typeof(pstrSpanID) == cTYPEOF_IS_STRING )
    {   // Explicitly cast pstrSpanID to a string, to simplify subsequent processing.
        var strSpanIDString = pstrSpanID.toString( );

        if ( strSpanIDString.length > cLENGTH_OF_EMPTY_STRING )
        {
            document.getElementById( strSpanIDString ).innerHTML = document.title;
        }   // TRUE block, if ( strSpanIDString.length > cLENGTH_OF_EMPTY_STRING )
        else
        {   // Degenerate case 3 of 3: Use the default placeholder span ID.
            document.getElementById( cDEFAULT_PAGE_TITLE_SPAN_PLACEHOLDER ).innerHTML = document.title;
        }   // FALSE block, if ( strSpanIDString.length > cLENGTH_OF_EMPTY_STRING )
    }   // TRUE block, else if (typeof(pstrSpanID) == cTYPEOF_IS_STRING )
    else
    {   // Degenerate case 2 of 3: Use the default placeholder span ID.
        document.getElementById( cDEFAULT_PAGE_TITLE_SPAN_PLACEHOLDER ).innerHTML = document.title;
    }   // FALSE block, if ( typeof (pstrSpanID) == cTYPEOF_IS_UNDEFINED ) and else if (typeof(pstrSpanID) == cTYPEOF_IS_STRING )
}   // cphSetTitleFromTag
```

OK, guys, I know this function is overkill, but it buys me the flexibility to choose a different element ID, without touching this routine, and it attempts to fail gracefully when it gets the empty string, by treating it as equivalent to omitting the argument entirely, which is covered by the test for typeof being equal to "undefined" in the opening statement.

With this short JavaScript event handler safely tucked away in an external script file, getting the title text at run time from the title tag requires just two things.

1. The external script file is linked to your page as shown above.
2. The Body tag has the onload="cphSetTitleFromTag()" attribute, which causes JavaScript function **cphSetTitleFromTag** to be called without arguments when the page has finished loading.
3. The tag within which you want the title to appear has the designated **ID** attribute. My choice of **H1** is arbitrary.

For your convenience, I have posted the JavaScript library at [commonPageHelpers.js](http://www.wizardwrx.com/commonPageHelpers.js).

In closing, the foregoing method works in any environment in which the client runs JavaScript; the server can be anything, although ASP.NET pages can accomplish this feat on the server side.